# How to organize infinite loop with symbols analysis in it?

Tags: c++, loops

I need to organize infinite loop with symbol analysis in it. In C I used `fgets(buf, N, stdin)`, suppose `buf` is `buf[10]`. User could type string of any length and I could analyze it by breaking down the input and examining parts of length 10. How can I implement this in C++ without using C libraries. Sorry for my English if you can't understand what I mean

Comment: I'm not getting where symbols analysis comes into it.

Comment: when they get into the buf, I want to analyze them one by one and then get a new portion. It's important for me not to store any string, but to "flow" the input through the buf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ you should `std::cin` to read from standard input.

```
// #include <iostream>

do
{
    char buf[10]{}; // create array of 10 bytes filled with zeros.
    std::cin.read(buf, 10); // read 10 bytes

    // at this point you should check if std::cin.read succeeded.
    // otherwise you will be reading zeros.

    std::streamsize numRead = std::cin.gcount(); // obtain number of read bytes.
    std::cout << numRead << " " << buf << std::endl; // some printing.
}while(std::cin);
```

Comment: might be better to use a `do while` because the last read will return falsey even if there's bytes left to analyze. Also some explaination would be nice as code-only answers are frowned upon

Comment: Hmm, to be honest I don't understand. In which case "last read" can leave bytes to analyze? Edit: okay, I get it. You are right.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x The only difference between a `while` and a `do while` is that `do while` is guaranteed to execute the body at least once. They'll both act the same way when the condition becomes false (assuming the body has already been executed once).

Comment: @scohe001 he is right. At last reading, `std::cin.read` returns false, since the buffer ended, but `buf` still contains data to analyze. I need to change this answer.

Comment: That is correct (as long as the input is not a multiple of 10 bytes long)

Comment: @razzorflame I agree that he is correct that your answer won't work for all cases as of now, but his solution to make it a do-while will illicit the same behavior (assuming there's more than 10 bytes in stdin).

Comment: Okay, now it should be correct.

Comment: Not quite. You use `buf` before verifying `std::cin.read(buf, 10);` was successful.

Comment: Its filled with zeros, so it is not a big problem, however I will add a notice.